# InDesign: Javascript grep last match in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, grep, adobe-indesign

I have here a text in InDesign:

```
Hello (World),
this (nonsense) text
nobody (needs, right?).
```

With my jsx script I want to select the last match with brackets `(needs, right?)`.
But this result is formatted with regular and italic (`needs` is italic and the rest is regular). But I only want to change the regular style.

The part in my script looks like this:

```
function myFindGrep(myObject, mySearchString, mySearchStyle, myStyleGroup, myStyle){
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = mySearchString;
    app.findGrepPreferences.fontStyle = mySearchStyle;
    app.changeGrepPreferences.appliedCharacterStyle = myDocument.characterStyleGroups.item(myStyleGroup).characterStyles.item(myStyle);
    var myFoundItems = myObject.changeGrep();
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
}

myFindGrep(selText.paragraphs.item(x), "\(.+?\)", "Regular", "Meist genutzte", "Zitat Regular");
```

When I apply this, it change my hole selection except the italic Text...

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your script seems to do the work for what I can observe.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify my function, to do a second grep:

```
function myFindQuote(myObject, mySearchString, mySearchStyle, myStyleGroup, myStyle) {
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = mySearchString;
    var myFoundItems = myObject.findGrep();

    for (var i = 0; i < myFoundItems.length; i++) {
        app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
        app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
        app.findGrepPreferences.fontStyle = mySearchStyle;
        app.changeGrepPreferences.appliedCharacterStyle = myDocument.characterStyleGroups.item(myStyleGroup).characterStyles.item(myStyle);
        myFoundItems[i].changeGrep();
    }
}
```